# Neo4j Cypher Recursively traverse until a specific node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a recursive query that will start from a specific node but wants to stop the recursion when it reaches to the specific node.

For example

```
  (node{Id:1})-[Parent]->(node{Id:2})
    (node{Id:2})-[Parent]->(node{Id:3})
    (node{Id:3})-[Parent]->(node{Id:4})
....
....
(node{Id:99})-[Parent]->(node{Id:100})
```

Now I want to traverse from node 3 to node 8.

I tried below query but it traverses from node 3 to the root node (ie node 100).

```
match  (c:node{Id:3})-[Parent*0..]->(p:node) retun p;
```

How can I put a condition here to stop the traversal when I reach to the node 8?

Comment: It's not clear from your question why you are matching other nodes as you are returning only last node i.e. p and not using other nodes/path here.

Comment: Since this is recursive, "return p" will return all the nodes in the path.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `Id` parameter in Match clause to the second node(here p) as well.

```
MATCH path=(c:node{Id:3})-[Parent*0..]->(p:node{Id:8}) RETURN path;
```

You can also add depth in Relationship match like `[Parent*0..N]` If you know the exact or max value of N.

**EDIT:**
Above query returns path from node 3 to 8. If you are looking for only nodes in the path from node 3 to 8, You can match the path and return nodes present on that path.

```
MATCH path=(c:node{Id:3})-[Parent*0..]->(p:node{Id:8}) RETURN nodes(path);
```

Comment: You can also add a LIMIT if you only need a certain number of results.

Comment: If I add Id parameter in match clause it returns only that node with Id=8. I want to retrieve all nodes from node 3 to node 8

Comment: In that case, you need to return path from node 3 to 8.